# Auto layout: Pin right edge to superview

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I'm trying to programmatically layout a view with Auto Layout and every time I try to pin a subview to the right edge, the subview disappears.

My layout is like this:

```
---------------------
- label1     label2 -
-                   -
---------------------
```

I'm trying the following constraints:

```
    [insetView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-(55.0)-[label1]" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary]];
    [insetView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-(29.0)-[label1]" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary]];
    [insetView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-(55.0)-[label2]" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary]];
    [insetView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"[label2]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary]];
```

Is it possible that the last constraint is actually pinning the RIGHT edge of label2 to the LEFT edge of its superview?

Comment: I don't know how to solve your visual constraint problem because they're ridiculous! But have you considered something like [Masonry](https://github.com/Masonry/Masonry) instead?

Comment: For starters, are you sure translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints is set to `NO` for your two labels? Also, are any AutoLayout warnings printed when you run your app?

Comment: Autoresizing contraints are turned off and no warnings. :)

Comment: Try using view debugging built into Xcode 6.  When you do that, it will show you where the label is and also the run time constraints. Here is a [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-debugger/using_view_debugger/using_view_debugger.html) to an Apple doc that describes the basics of using it.